# Bazel. Is there any way of running script under the same directory without `--run_under`?

Tags: bazel

### Summary

I'd like to reduce the number of types when formatting.

### Status quo

I am using Bazel to manage C++ project. Below is the simplified structure of the project.

```sh
❯ tree
.
├── bin
│  ├── BUILD.bazel
│  └── format.sh
├── README.md
├── src
└── WORKSPACE
```

Now, I'd like to format all files in `src` (off course, I have `test` in my real project) by `bin/format.sh`.

However, it really bothers me to type the long command below. Do you know how to make it easier?(If it is possible to change the command to`bazel run bin:format`, that's perfect.)

I think adding some codes in `bin/BUILD.bazel` would help, but I don't have any idea.

```sh
bazel run --run_under="cd $PWD &&" bin:format # format source codes
```

#### contents of files

```
sh_binary(
    name = "format",
    srcs = ["format.sh"],
)
```

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
buildifier -r .
find . -iname *.h -o -iname *.cc | xargs clang-format -i -style=Google
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are doing is fine. I would just define an alias as in

```
alias clang-fmt='bazel run --run_under="${PWD}" //bin:format'
```

You could also not use the `--run_under` option, and pass the directory to the program:

```
alias clang-fmt='bazel run //bin:format -- "${PWD}"'
```

and update the script

```
find $1 -iname *.h -o -iname *.cc | xargs clang-format -i -style=Google
```